# Webpack 4 - Non NPM Vendor Directory

Tags: webpack, frontend, asset-pipeline, webpack-4

At the moment I'm trying to build a prototype of my idea, and bought a Bootstrap theme on Themeforest. Being a Frontend noob that I am, I can't seem to find concrete information how to produce `vendor.js` and `vendor.css` from the theme's provided assets directory.

So far, these seems the most reliable sources:

- https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/
- https://medium.com/@hpux/webpack-4-in-production-how-make-your-life-easier-4d03e2e5b081
- https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-4-code-splitting-chunk-graph-and-the-splitchunks-optimization-be739a861366

Any config example or some sort of detail guide would be really helpful!

Thank you!

Comment: there are some examples in webpack's github repo.    Check [common-chunk-and-vendor-chunk](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/common-chunk-and-vendor-chunk) and [code-splitted-css-bundle](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/code-splitted-css-bundle)

Comment: @loveky ah~! that is very helpful! I see the important bit is in each page's `pageX.js`, and webpack produces very nice assets per page. I was thinking along the line of Rail's assets compiling and blatantly place _all_ vendors in to one big file. It is probably an anti-pattern, but is webpack capable of this? Thank you.

Comment: check this [config](https://gist.github.com/loveky/3a2cbb393cbae5466da9bf1b018e8d81)